# Problem extracting specific values from API using JSON

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am experiencing a problem getting data from an API and was wondering if someone could help please. I basically the value 'low_14h' has a number of responses in different currencies. I would just like to be able to extract the value in 'usd' and put it into my textbox 'dailylowtext'. I can get close with fiddling around and get some of the values from 'low_24h', but am struggling to just about get the value from 'usd'. Hopefully this makes sense what it is I'm trying to achieve.

My current code is:

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/mina-protocol";

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject(response.toString());
                String usd = jObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONObject("low_24h").getString("usd").toString();



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dailylowtext.setText(response.toString());
            System.out.println("Response => "+response.toString());


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Comment: What does the JSON actually look like? Provide an example

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your post. The problem has since been resolved. Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot the "market_data". In the JSON's file, market_data is the parent of low_24.

[image]

You don't have a "response" node in your JSON's data, try with market_data instead of response.

```java
String usd = jObj.getJSONObject("market_data").getJSONObject("low_24h").getString("usd").toString();
```

You can also use library such as [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) that will help you to work with JSON data.

Comment: This worked straight away when I changed it to reflect. Thank you so much! How could I miss "market_data"!? Feel so silly now. Your help has been very much appreciated, take care and have a great Christmas.